# How to pass python variable to bash shell part of the same file?

Tags: python, python-3.x, bash

I have python app that runs some bash commands. Bash shell commands get network bandwidth so it need device name (enp35s0) of my gnu/linux machine.

I run python app typing `sudo main.py en35s0` then enp35s0 going to 'n' variable. Below in the same file I have to pass n variable to bash part of app.

main.py

```
    #!/usr/bin/python3
    import os
    import sys
    import subprocess
    import time
    
    n = (sys.argv[1])
    print(n)
    
    
    def capture():
        subprocess.run(["pkexec", '/bin/bash', '-c', bash], check=True)
    
    bash = '''
    #!/usr/bin/env bash
    #set -x
    
    INTERVAL="1"  # update interval in seconds
    
    
    #-----HERE I MUST PASS N VARIABLE----
    
    n=enp35s0
    
    # How many time script will work.
    start=1
    end=8 # put the number for minues. 3600 is 1 hour.
    
    
    
    while [[ $start -le $end ]]
    do
        #echo "$start"
        ((start = start + 1))
    
        # Capture packets.
        R1=`cat /sys/class/net/$n/statistics/rx_bytes`
        T1=`cat /sys/class/net/$n/statistics/tx_bytes`
        sleep $INTERVAL
        R2=`cat /sys/class/net/$n/statistics/rx_bytes`
        T2=`cat /sys/class/net/$n/statistics/tx_bytes`
        TBPS=`expr $T2 - $T1`
        RBPS=`expr $R2 - $R1`
        TKBPS=`expr $TBPS / 1024`
        RKBPS=`expr $RBPS / 1024`
        echo "TX $1: $TKBPS kB/s RX $1: $RKBPS kB/s"
....
....
....

capture()
```

Comment: You can search for "string formatting in python"

Comment: @Asocia I didn't find any example "string formatting in python" that help me. Would you like to show me a example?

Answer (score 0):

Use .format like this

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

default_var = 'AAA'

some_text_var = '''
some text
insert your new var here {value}
some more text
'''.format(value=default_var)
```

Testing:

```
>>> print(some_text_var)

some text
insert your new var here AAA
some more text
```

Comment: your example don't help me. I said variable take from argument. Your example I have to put manually.

Comment: @user19127009 it's the same thing. It doesn't matter whether it comes from command line arguments or you set it in your code directly.

Comment: @Asocia It doesn't same thing. Every machine I have to edit the app and change variable. I want to put automatically from argument that type a user.

Comment: @user19127009 it is indeed the same thing. You are capturing the command line argument with `n = (sys.argv[1])`. Just pass that `n` variable to wherever it should go. If you search for "string formatting in python" you will get there, believe me.

Answer (score 0):

**Example**.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import sys
import subprocess

n = ""    
script = "date.sh"   # /path/to/your/shell/script.sh
if len(sys.argv) > 1:
    n = sys.argv[1]

def capture():
    subprocess.run(["/bin/bash", script, n], check=True)
capture()
```

My shell sctipt

```
$ cat date.sh
date $@
```

Exec

```
$ ./test.py 
Sat 18 Jun 2022 09:48:51 PM CEST

$ ./test.py "+%Y"
2022
```

Comment: I don't have separate file with bash shell commands. It is one file. Did you see where have to be variable? It doesn't work.

Comment: @user19127009 better you use a separate file for your shell code or just change line 9 of your shell script  to `n='''+n+'''`.

Comment: subprocess.run line works without n `subprocess.run(["/bin/bash", script]..` why?